# Simple contact form mailer

Tags: php, html, css, forms

Well I'm working on my first PHP code, in the way of a simple form mailer. I can't seem to see why its generating the error

> We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you
>   submitted. These errors appear below.
>
> We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you
>   submitted.
>
> Please go back and fix these errors.

If anyone well versed in PHP sees the issue, I'd appreciate any guidance you can give.

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend> Error Report:</legend>
<p><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" autofocus></p>
<p><input name="email" type="text" placeholder="email@domain.com"></p>
<p><textarea name="descpirtion" placeholder="Give a description of the error."></textarea></p>
<p><label>What internet browser were you using when the error occured?</label></p>
<p><select name="browser"><option>Internet Explorer</option><option>Chrome</option><option>Safari</option><option>Firefox</option></select></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" value="Cancel"></p>
</fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

the CSS

```
body {background: #222; padding: 1em; margin: 0; font-size: 16px; color: #777;}
     body * {margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;}
     p {margin: 0 0 1em; font-size: 14px;}

    input, textarea, select {
     border: 1px solid #111;
     border-radius: 5px;
     padding: 0.5em;
     font-size: 15px;
     line-height: 1.2em;
     width: 80%;
     background: #444;
     color: #999;
     font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#222), to(#444));
     -webkit-appearance: none;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
     }

     input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus {outline-color: #FC0;}

   textarea {
       color: #999;
       border-radius: 5px;
       height: 55px;
       background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #222), color-stop(0.05, #333));
   }

   select {
       color: #999;
       border-radius: 5px;
       padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 0.75em;
       background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #222), color-stop(0.05, #333));
}


     input[type=text] {
     color: #999;
     border-radius: 5px;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #222), color-stop(0.12, #333));
   }

   input[type=submit] {
     color:#FFF;
     border-radius: 5px;
     width: auto;
     padding: 0.25em 1em;
     line-height: 1.5em;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FC0), to(#FF0));
     border: 2px solid #FC0;
     text-shadow: 0 0 2px #300;
     font-weight: bold;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
     margin-right: 0.5em;
   }

   input[type=reset] {
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: auto;
      padding: 0.25em 1em;
      line-height: 1.5em;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#333), to(#222));
      border: 2px solid #444;
      text-shadow: 0 0 2px #300;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #999;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    }
label{
    color: #999;
}

leged{
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

the PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "webmaster@canyonlakemma.com";
    $email_subject = "Website Error Report";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['description']) ||
        !isset($_POST['browser'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $description = $_POST['description']; // required
    $browser = $_POST['browser']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'Be sure to include your name.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($description) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'Please include a description of the error.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($browser) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'Please select your browser.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Description: ".clean_string($description)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Browser: ".clean_string($broswer)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!isset($_POST['description'])` doesn't use the same id as `<textarea name="descpirtion"`

desc-p-i-r-tion ;)

Comment: OK I feel like a tool now. but thank you. Unfortunately its created a new issue. Rather than submitting and mailing, its showing me the entire PHP file upon submission. I have PHP installed on my local machine (a full web server in fact). Now its a matter of finding if its a line of code here or something with the webserver. My IPS blocks inbound traffic but it should still work for sending information out to the web.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct, but to be more specific, you have mis-spelled "description" in your "name" value of the HTML textarea form field here:

```
<p><textarea name="***descpirtion***" placeholder="....
```

It needs to match the lines in your script here:

```
$description = $_POST['description']; // required
!isset($_POST['description']) ||
```

Did the exact same thing myself yesterday, and spend an hour or more debugging my PHP when it was a simple typo.

Comment: bah I was going to up vote your responce as well since I accepted samsamX's answer but I can't until I get some 'rep'. But anyway you've helped as well thank you!